# Installer flags file in use when it is not

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WIX installer which updates an SNMP Agent dll.  I have a custom action which stops the SNMP service.  When the installer runs the log file always says the file is in use when it is not.  When reviewing the installer log the log entries appear to be bassackwards. File copy log entries are written after the installed services and SNMP service have all already started. The file is updated and the SNMP Service starts with the newly copied file. No reboot is necessary however MSI is setting the reboot flag.  Here's a snippet of my log file. Can anyone make sense of this order of operations issue?

`
...

Action ended 14:59:57: StopSnmpService. Return value 1.

...

MSI (s) (4C:04) [14:59:58:982]: Doing action: InstallFiles

...

MSI (s) (4C:04) [14:59:59:029]: Doing action: InstallServices

Action 14:59:59: InstallServices. Installing new services

Action start 14:59:59: InstallServices.

InstallServices: Service:

Action ended 14:59:59: InstallServices. Return value 1.

MSI (s) (4C:04) [14:59:59:029]: Doing action: StartServices

Action 14:59:59: StartServices. Starting services

Action start 14:59:59: StartServices.

StartServices: Service: Starting services

Action ended 14:59:59: StartServices. Return value 1.

...

MSI (s) (4C:04) [14:59:59:045]: Doing action: StartSnmpService

...

MSI (s) (4C:04) [14:59:59:560]: File: C:\Program Files\Corner Bowl\Server Manager 2022\cbsmsnmpagent.dll;   Overwrite;  Won't patch;    Existing file is a lower version

MSI (s) (4C:04) [14:59:59:560]: Source for file 'cbsmsnmpagent.dll' is compressed
InstallFiles: File: cbsmsnmpagent.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\Corner Bowl\Server Manager 2022,  Size: 19968

MSI (s) (4C:04) [14:59:59:560]: Re-applying security from existing file.
Info 1603. The file C:\Program Files\Corner Bowl\Server Manager 2022\cbsmsnmpagent.dll is being held in use. Close that application and retry.

MSI (s) (4C:04) [15:00:02:919]: Verifying accessibility of file: cbsmsnmpagent.dll
...
`

Answer (score 0):

This is a downside of reinventing the wheel with a custom action.  If you used the ServiceControl element then MSI would know that this service will be stopped and the file won't really be in use.  But since your doing it out of process with custom code it doesn't know this and you get an erroneous message.

Comment: I fixed the issue by moving the Start SNMP Service action to after InstallFinalize.  I see I guess I could have add service control functions to the MSI directly.  Since it's an OS service I guess I thought I should do the custom action.

Comment: Moving it to after InstallFinalize isn't a great choice because it's outside of the installation transaction which will break rollbacks.  Also the custom action won't always have the needed permissions because immediate custom actions run outside of the transaction will run in the user context.